# Codeigniter route want remove node

Tags: codeigniter, routes

In my codeigniter fronend module file $route variable is as follows
$route['node/:any/'] = array('action' => 'node');

it works like below
if we put www.example.com/node/aboutus/ in URL it is giving aboutus page.
if we put www.example.com/node/privacy-policy/ it is giving privacy policy page.

Now I want to put www.example.com/aboutus/ in URL I want that aboutus page.
Now I want to put www.example.com/privacy-policy/ in URL I want that privacy policy page.

Basically I want to remove node from URL. 
Here my controller is frontendController and action is node.
In node action I'm fetching my pages store in database. I have lot of pages stored in database.

So what I have to write in fronend module file or in route file for removing node from URL

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in the routes.php file(present in config folder):

```
$route['route_you_want_to_show'] = "current_route";
```

i.e. in your case

```
$route['www.example.com/aboutus/'] = "www.example.com/node/aboutus/";
```

Now change the links on your site from '*www.example.com/node/aboutus/*' to *'www.example.com/aboutus/'* and its ready to work as you want.

But mind well in codeigniter routes are formed from the redirection of code to controller and its methods.